# Regular Expression to find next word after the match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a statement like `Data lva_var type Integer value 20`. I need to find out the token after `type`.

My latest try was `[type](?:\s\S+)`, but the match was `e integer`.

Code snippets would be helpful.

Comment: You've tagged this with three different languages/environments - where do you need the Regex?

Comment: I need a general regular expression

Comment: You misunderstand the question - **which language will you be using this regular expression in?** They vary, and you've marked it in two specific / different languages.  Which is it?

Answer (score 7):

Just try this, 
`type\s(\w+)`
Here the first group contains the word next to "type"
Hope this code helps.

Comment: It should not match the word 'type', it must just match a word after it excluding that word.

Comment: The parentheses will capture the word after 'type' separately. See this for how to get it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Comment: @AKHILRAJ as Adam mentioned the parentheses will capture your token as a seperate group.

Answer (score 3):

You can use lookbehind for this `(?<=\btype\s)(\w+)` will do the trick for you. Take a look at [this example](https://regex101.com/r/hA9iO1/1).

Comment: Please view edited answer, code was included in the provided link ( as it still is ).

Comment: Thanks.  Just helping you understand "best practices". If the link ever breaks, that service ever goes away, etc, your code would be lost.  Further, having the code in your answer saves future visitors time.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds, but since you tagged `nsregularexpression` and that does support them, maybe try this: `(?<=\btype\s+)\w+`