# Find the next word after a particular word in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I want to find all the words that occur after a particular word. For eg:

`I want to deliver goods from Indonesia to India`

Here, I want all the words that occur after **to** ,so the result should be an array containing **deliver** and **India**

Comment: Can you show your attempted regex

Comment: I didn't try with regex. I was thinking of using index and then find the next word.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412759/5527985

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = 'I want to deliver goods from Indonesia to India to';
let arr = str.split(' ');
let words_following_to = [];

arr.map((word, i) => {
    if (word.toLowerCase() === 'to' && arr[i + 1]) {
        words_following_to.push(arr[i + 1]);
    }
});

console.log(words_following_to); // [ 'deliver', 'India' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this:

```
const str = 'I want to deliver goods from Indonesia to India';
str.match(/(?<=to\s+)(\w+)/g)
```